# Using an Azure Web Function to receive a Twilio SMS Message

Tags: azure, twilio, azure-webjobs

I'm trying to get an Azure Web Function to receive a Twilio SMS message - and failing!

I've created a Web Function to successfully send SMS messages - now I want to listen and react to responses.

I've set up a web function as per the below.  Its pretty simple at the moment, and is supposed to parrot back the original message:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var data = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var formValues = data.Split('&')
                .Select(value => value.Split('='))
                .ToDictionary(pair => Uri.UnescapeDataString(pair[0]).Replace("+", " "),
                              pair => Uri.UnescapeDataString(pair[1]).Replace("+", " "));

            // Perform calculations, API lookups, etc. here

            var response = new MessagingResponse()
                .Message($"You said: {formValues["Body"]}");
            var twiml = response.ToString();
            twiml = twiml.Replace("utf-16", "utf-8");

            return new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                Content = new StringContent(twiml, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")
            };
        }
```

In Twilio, I've configured the phone to use web hooks:

[image]

I've deployed the Web Function, however when I try testing by sending a message, I get the following error in the Twilio logs:

11200 There was a failure attempting to retrieve the contents of this URL
Msg Unsupported Media Type
Message: The WebHook request must contain an entity body formatted as JSON.

Does anyone have any experience in how to fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

I just got this working with Twilio's SMS services. In the Azure Portal, if you go to the function, then go to Integrate, change the mode to Standard. This forces the Azure function to return a normal HTTP response and you can control the content type. If you use application/xml it will work fine.

Comment: Nice work @TheCodeMonk!  I'll have to give this a go as I would rather use a Web Function over a full web app.

Comment: I was getting the same error while trying to parse the data posted by Kentico Cloud webhook to an Azure Function inside a Logic App. This simple solution worked like a charm!

Comment: @TheCodeMonk, I think because the interface has changed, I cannot find the exact setting you mentioned when you wrote, "In the Azure Portal, if you go to the function, then go to Integrate, change the mode to Standard". There is so less documention available online that we are stuck. Can you please tell me, where to find this setting ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the current solution to this is .... it can't be done in Azure Web Functions.  An Azure Web Function expects a JSON payload.  Twilio Webhooks are an XML value/pair.  So, the web function will reject the webhook call.

The best/easiest approach is to use a WebAPI or MVC Controller as per the Twilio example.  I tried a sample version and had my Twilio Webhooks working to reply to an SMS in about 15 minutes from start to finish.

Answer (score 0):

To debug, I'd use a tool such as Postman or Fiddler to manually replay (or create from scratch) an identical request to what you're expecting from Twilio. You can then see what kind of response you get and not have to solely rely on Twilio's error message.

From the error code, I'd imagine that the problem is either:

- Your URL set up in the Twilio number configuration isn't actually reaching your function.
- Your function is taking too long to respond. Twilio will throw 11200 if it doesn't get a response in a certain time.
- Your response is formatted incorrectly. This is where the aforementioned strategy can help you diagnose the issue.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  Is there a way of directing the Twilioo response to be in a JSON format rather than XML?

Comment: Now that I take a closer look at your code, are you trying to send an automatic reply via SMS back to whatever number you received the message from?

Comment: Initially I was sending a response back just to get the code working. Eventually I want to log the response to a database for a poor mans chat application

Comment: I am working from memory here, but if I recall, you need to send a HTTP 200 response back to Twilio's callback. Optionally, you can fire off a response within your function body, but that's a separate web service call. Try returning HTTP 200 and nothing else in your Function response above, and see if the error goes away.

Comment: No, it made no difference.  It looks like the Twilio request is being denied by the Web Function with:  The WebHook request must contain an entity body formatted as JSON.  I'm not sure where to change this in the web function config.